# How to compile multiple Java files with Jar dependencies?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

Other similar answers on StackOverflow do not exactly answer the question.

I am running Windows and have two folders: *lib* and *src*. *lib* contains *.jar* files for dependencies. I attempted to compile via:

```
javac -cp ".;lib/*" *.java
```

It worked. Each file has a *.class* file and the *.java* file with the main class has an additional *Controller$1.class* named file.

I attempted to run the program via all of the following:

```
java -cp ".;lib/*" src/Controller
java -cp ".;lib/*" src/Controller.class
java -cp ".;lib/*" src/Controller$1.class
```

None of the above methods worked. They all gave me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Controller
```

What is the problem and how do I do this? It works fine in my IDE, but a company I'm interviewing for wants it with the JAR files included and compilable and runnable via command line. I haven't compiled stuff like that in literally ages, so some help will be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, how can I compile and run the things if they have a deeper folder structure. For example if I have the following folders / paths:

```
lib/
src/
src/core
src/models
src/models/enums
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure seems to be like this:

```
root:
lib
src: Controller.java and other files without a package
```

Correct commands:

```
javac -sourcepath src -d lib src/*.java
java -cp lib Controller
```

Explanation:

```
javac -cp ".;lib/*" *.java
java -cp ".;lib/*" src/Controller
```

You did not copy any class in lib but your "cp" is set to lib. Also the class Controller has no package so:

```
java -cp "lib" Controller
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to be using the `javac`, and not `java` for those commands you mention, see below:

```
javac -cp ".;lib/*" src/Controller.java
```

Also, what are you using to build the project? If you are using Maven, there are some great plugins that will make your life much easier in terms of packaging a JAR with its dependencies.

Comment: I'm not using anything, that's the point. Also, javac is for compiling, isn't it? I've already compiled them, I can't run them.

Comment: Yes, javac is for compiling